# Random number seed in numpy

Tags: numpy, random-seed

```
numpy.random.seed(7)
```

In different machine learning and data analysis tutorials, I saw this seed set with a different number. Does it make a real difference in choosing a specific seed number? Or any number is fine? The goal of choosing a seed number is to reproducibility of the same experiments.

Comment: Yes, any number will do. It's just for the sake of reproducibility.

Comment: No any difference? Some people use a very big number, some people use a small number. Then why not have a numpy.random.seed() function with a default seed in the implementation? Users don't have to pass a seed into it. I am afraid the seed have a use.

Answer (score 3):

Supplying the same seed will give the same results every time the program is run. This is useful during developing/testing to reliably get the same results over and over.

When your app is "in production", change the seed source to something dynamic, like the current time (or something less predictable) to have "typical random behavior". If you don't supply a seed, many generators will default to something like the current time as milliseconds since some epoch.

The actual number doesn't matter. I use my school ID number (9 digits), just out of habit since I have it thoroughly memorized, but also use short 2 digits numbers for quick tests if I want it to be reproducible.

Comment: In production, why do you still need this random number, since you don't need to get the same result?

Comment: School id is too long. just use '0' or '1'?

Comment: @user697911 In many languages/libraries, if you don't supply a number, it will default to something like the current time. This could be potentially dangerous if you're writing something like lottery software where such default behavior could make the random numbers predictable; especially if the end user knows/can guess what the random number source is.

Comment: @user697911 Ya, you can use any number. I just use by ID because that's the seed I've tested with for years now. It's arbitrary.